# Struts2 + <s:select/> tag + "headerValue" attribute

Tags: struts2

Is it possible to get the value of "headerValue" attribute in the "select" tag from resource bundle in case I am using internationalization?

What are other possible options?

BR 
SC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can... hope you already have have a property file...

In Properties file,

```
propertyKey=List Header Value
```

Call it as follows in  tag,

```
<s:select list="itemList" headerKey="0" headerValue="%{getText('propertyKey')}"/>
```

Hope this will help....